# Elasticsearch inaccurate score for symbol searching

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I've two stores named, `face-` and `face+ store`

when I search for `face+`, i want the list of results to be:

1. `face+ store`
2. `face-`

But, the results are

1. `face-`
2. `face+ store`

My custom analyzer will produce tokens like this

`face-` to `[face, face-]`

`face+ store` to `[face, face+, +store, store]`

this is my query

```
multi_match: {
  query: keywords,
  type: "best_fields",
  fields: ['name.analyzed^10','name.word_middle^5'],
  analyzer: "custom_analyzer",
}
```

this is my mapping, if it helps

```
analysis: {
  analyzer: {
    custom_analyzer: {
      type: "custom",
      char_filter: ["ampersand", "sym_repl"],
      tokenizer: "whitespace",
      filter: ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "searchkick_index_shingle", "searchkick_stemmer", "del_sym"]
    }
  },
  char_filter: {
    # adding a space between those patterns
    sym_repl: {
      type: "pattern_replace",
      pattern: '[.+\-*|\]\)\"#@&!]',
      replacement: " $0 "
    }
  },
  filter: {
    # remove token that match the stopwords
    del_sym: {
      type: "stop",
      stopwords: ['.', '+', '-', '*', '|', ']', ')', '"', '#', '@', '&', '!']
    }
  }
}

mappings: {
  store: {
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: "keyword",
        fields: {
          analyzed: {
            type: "text",
            analyzer: "custom_analyzer"
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: can you share your analyzer definition ?

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to produce your issue, as you are using `searchkick. but if you use` minimum_should_match`with value 2 and create a proper query, it will filter`face-` from the search result and that is what you want.

Comment: thats not working for me as still want `face-` in my results.
just i need `face+` to be in the first list.